# How can a daemon user connect through SSH?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I have launched process named redmine that launched by deamon user – redmine. Some inner redmine (as process) plugin needs SSH connection to outer service and make it from redmine (user), but this deamon user not specified for this.

Is the only way to achive my goal to login as redmine user and create `/bin/.ssh/authorized_keys`? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you have a system user `redmine` which is dedicated to running a specific service.

Do the administration of that account as root. For example, if the account needs to have an SSH key, use the root account to copy that key.

`~/.ssh` can belong to root. For a system account that isn't supposed to do its own maintenance, `~/.ssh` *should* belong to root and not be writable by the user. That way, if the account is compromise, the attacker can affect the service but has limited opportunities to escalate access or to use the machine as a relay.

Do give the account a dedicated home directory, not `/bin`.